# An algorithm to find common edits

Tags: algorithm

I've got two word lists, an example:

```
 list 1  list 2

 foot    fuut
 barj    kijo
 foio    fuau
 fuim    fuami
 kwim    kwami
 lnun    lnun
 kizm    kazm
```

I'd like to find

```
o → u # 1 and 3
i → a # 3 and 7
im → ami # 4 and 5
```

This should be ordered by amount of occurrences, so I can filter the
ones that don't appear often.

The lists currently consist of 35k words, the calculation should
take about 6h on an average server.

Comment: Do you also want to find the i -> a in 4 and 5?  In other words, would you count that i to a occurs 4 times above or only 2?

Comment: Good question. I think if the change occurs as a part of another change, it shouldn't be counted. So, I count only 2.

Comment: do you have a limit for length of words?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, do you looking for minimum amount of changes?

Comment: I'm looking for patterns, changes that occur often in the word list.

Comment: Is it also possible to have `a`-> `i` in one case and `a`-> `b` in another case (assume both of them are in same word list).

Comment: Sure. I won't like that result, but it may happen.

Comment: As I can see in your sample, you compared first item from list1 with first item in list2, .. i'th item in list1 with i'th item in list2? or no arbitrary comparing items (e.g item1 in list1 could be converted to item2 in list2?)

Comment: No, the pairings are given, and they're not arbitrary, rather different dialects of a language.

Comment: Why o->u but not oo->uu and
im -> ami instead of i->a and m->mi
As I understand if you want to search by most often occurrence you should split them as much as possible.

Comment: Re:May 19 at 18:42 But in this case you should treat 3 as oio->uau but not as o->u and i->a

Comment: please take a look at my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution is to use the mosesdecoder. I split the words into
single characters and used them as parallel corpus and used the
extracted model. I compared Sursilvan and Vallader.

```
export IRSTLM=$HOME/rumantsch/mosesdecoder/tools/irstlm
export PATH=$PATH:$IRSTLM/bin

rm -rf corpus giza.* model
array=("sur" "val")
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    cp "raw.$i" "splitted.$i"
    sed -i 's/ /@/g' "splitted.$i"
    sed -i 's/./& /g' "splitted.$i"
    add-start-end.sh < "splitted.$i" > "compiled.$i"
    build-lm.sh -i "compiled.$i" -t ./tmp -p -o "compiled.lm.$i"
    compile-lm --text yes "compiled.lm.$i.gz" "compiled.arpa.$i"
done

../scripts/training/train-model.perl --first-step 1 --last-step 5 -root-dir . -corpus splitted -f sur -e val -lm 0:3:$PWD/compiled.arpa.sur -extract-options "--SentenceId" -external-bin-dir ../tools/bin/

$HOME/rumantsch/mosesdecoder/scripts/../bin/extract $HOME/rumantsch/mosesdecoder/rumantsch/splitted.val $HOME/rumantsch/mosesdecoder/rumantsch/splitted.sur $HOME/rumantsch/mosesdecoder/rumantsch/model/aligned.grow-diag-final $HOME/rumantsch/mosesdecoder/rumantsch/model/extract 7 --SentenceId --GZOutput

zcat model/extract.sid.gz | awk -F '[ ][|][|][|][ ]' '$1!=$2{print $1, "|", $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10 > results
```

Comment: What is mosesdecoder? provide some links for different parts of your solution.

Comment: `Moses is a free software statistical machine translation engine that allows automatically training translation models for any language pair given a collection of source and target text pairs (parallel corpus). It is released under the LGPL licence and available both as source code and binaries for Windows and Linux.`

Answer (score 10):

Edit distance algorithms and Levenshtein distance like as [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) method are Beneficial. But they are used to change one word to another one, by these methods you can find out how to change one word to another word with minimum amount of changes. But they aren't useful to find minimum amount of changes in two dictionaries.

> The longest common subsequence (LCS) problem is to find the longest
>   subsequence common to all sequences in a set of sequences (often just
>   two). Note that subsequence is different from a substring, see
>   substring vs. subsequence. It is a classic computer science problem,
>   the basis of file comparison programs such as diff, and has
>   applications in bioinformatics.

By using LCS or any other methods,for each word in list1, find that how that word changes to another one in list 2.
for example,between foot & feet: LCS=FT ,difference = oo=>ee.
You should make a bipartite graph that the first part makes from difference words, and the second part makes from list1. Each node in the  second part is connected to its own related difference in the first part.

I'll suppose length and total part of words are limited.

We can model this problem with graphs. Assign each change to one node. e.g **e → i** (which determines one of a changes) is label for one node. 
for example,If all of the operation of the form p→q is set to one part in bipartite graph and total difference for each pair of word's is equal one and define Edge collection's that Edge `uv` connects vertex `U` to `V` if word(u) (in second part) for changing to correct word needs V's changes.You have a maximum 25*26 node in first part (for this example).
if In your case *length>=1* ,so you need set a limit. I'll assume maximum part of change to each word is equal 3.and so we have 3*35K maximum node in first part. Now you can solve problem by choose set of node in first part that can be covered maximum word in second part(your chose should occur word change to correct word).

Find minimum vertex cut in this graph, to find set of node that they can supply your request.and repeat cut vertex algorithm's until get good answer.

you can use some sort of bounds to reduce the size of graph, e.g remove all nodes in the first part which has degree `1`, because this nodes are connected to exactly one word, so they seems to be useless.

This graph simulation can solve your problem.
With current problem statement, this bounds of algorithm works properly.

for example:[image]

It is example for bounds in this graph(remove all node in operation part that they have 1 edge):

> 1-remove node 4 because it is only connected to (nod),then remove
>   node(nod) 2-remove node 2 because it is only connected to
>   (sghoul),then remove node(sghoul) 3-now remove node 3 because it is
>   only connected to (goud)[sghoul is removed last step],then remove
>   node(goud)

and now you have one operation oo=>ee and you can choose this.

I'll think more and try to edit this text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use edit distance algorithms, for example, [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It may be necessary to make some minor changes in algorithms to register exact modifications.

Comment: Look for dynamic programming and edit distance algorithms. See a good tutorial here : http://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/courses/cl2006/lect4-stredit.pdf