# Get one list of parents including all the children at least once in one to many relationship

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a one to many relationship between a Report and a Location. My goal is to narrow my list of Reports down to as few Reports as possible containing all of the Locations represented.

If I simplify it to lists of numbers it would look like the following with the key being the report and the array being the list of locations:

```
{
  1:[1,2],
  2:[1],
  3:[2,3],
  4:[1,3,4]
}
```

The ideal solution would be to select Reports `1 or 3` and `4`. Either `1` or `3` could be selected because they both include Location `2` and duplicate Location `1` with Report `4`. Report `4` needs selected because it is the only one with Location `4`.

Efficiency isn't a major concern. How is the best way to narrow the list down using PHP?

Comment: I'm confused. "select `1` and `4`..." is that report "1 and 4" or locations "1 and 4" or reports with those locations? Also, how are you determining that 1 and 4 need to be selected? how are "all of the locations represented"?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I updated my question to answer your first questions

Comment: Is it vital to get the absolute fewest reports possible?  Or are you just trying to shrink the list of reports in order to hit everything?  That is to say, if you can shrink a list of 100 reports down to 8 reports, but there's actually a 'better answer' of 7 reports - but it would take 10 times as long to find that 'better answer' ... which would you rather do?

Comment: @WolfmanJoe I would prefer to find the "better answer". Efficiency isn't a major concern.

Comment: the idea in this link maybe is useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665888/an-algorithm-to-find-common-edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If efficiency is not a problem as you have stated, I can propose you **O(2^n * k)** algorithm, where **n** is the number of lists and **k** is the sum of their lengths. Just take all possible combinations using bitmasks and for each of them calculate whether it covers everything or not.

P.S.
Here is an implementation(http://ideone.com/bAGpbL):

```
$arr = array(
  0 => array(1,2),
  1 => array(1),
  2 => array(2,3),
  3 => array(1,3,4),
);
// It is assumed that all indexes are sequential starting from 0
$total_cover = array();
foreach($arr as $sub_arr) {
    foreach($sub_arr as $value) {
        $total_cover[$value] = true;
    }
}
$n = count($arr);
$best_cover = array_keys($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < (1 << $n); $i++) {
    $cover = array();
    $selected_list = array();
    for($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
        if(($i >> $j) & 1) {
            $selected_list[] = $j;
            foreach($arr[$j] as $value) {
                $cover[$value] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    $good_cover = true;
    foreach($total_cover as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($cover[$key])) {
            $good_cover = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($good_cover && count($selected_list) < count($best_cover)) {
        $best_cover = $selected_list;
    }
}
var_dump($best_cover);
```

Answer (score 3):

NP-completeness strikes again.

The problem you're trying to solve is called [Set Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), and, sure enough, is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

This means that an "efficient" (read, polynomial-time) algorithm for it is unlikely to exist.

The good news is that there are simple approximation algorithms that give you a decent approximation.

See [this](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS105-Winter05/Notes/wan-ba-notes.pdf) for how the "obvious" greedy algorithm (at each point, pick the report with the largest number of uncovered locations) gives you a `log (R)` approximation, where `R` is the number of reports (actually, it's even better than that).